# Flutter how to get value from TextEditingController to another class

Tags: forms, flutter

I'm creating an App that would fetch data from an API endpoint and wanted to be able to set the endpoint url using a form. i read that i need to use global keys but not sure how , mostly i only using it to validate a form and did not comply with the new Flutter nullable feature.

api.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:futurebuilder_example/page/settings_page.dart';
import 'package:futurebuilder_example/model/devices.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

String url = url_from_TextEditingController; //get URL from form

class DeviceApi {
  static Future<List<Devices>> getDevices() async {
    final response = await http.get(url);
    print(response.statusCode);

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      return devicesFromJson(response.body);
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed to load devices');
    }
```

and here's the settings_page.dart for configuring the url value :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

// Define a custom Form widget.
class SettingsPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  SettingsPageState createState() {
    return SettingsPageState();
  }
}

class SettingsPageState extends State<SettingsPage> {
  final myController = TextEditingController(text: "Please Input API URL");
  final GlobalKey<SettingsPageState> key = new GlobalKey();
  void dispose() {
    myController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  getText() {
    return myController.text;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      // appBar: AppBar(
      //   title: Text('Retrieve Text Input'),
      // ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        child: TextField(
          controller: myController,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you haven't mention where you are calling your Api. Anyways you will definitely create a click event or tap event call call your api. You can just pass the value into function of the api class. For e.g.:-

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:futurebuilder_example/page/settings_page.dart';
import 'package:futurebuilder_example/model/devices.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;


class DeviceApi {


  static Future<List<Devices>> getDevices(String url) async {
    final response = await http.get(url);
    print(response.statusCode);

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    return devicesFromJson(response.body);
  } else {
    throw Exception('Failed to load devices');
}
```

the above class can be called in your stateful widget on a button tap event:-

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

// Define a custom Form widget.
class SettingsPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  SettingsPageState createState() {
  return SettingsPageState();
 }
}

class SettingsPageState extends State<SettingsPage> {
  final myController = TextEditingController(text: "Please Input API URL");
  final GlobalKey<SettingsPageState> key = new GlobalKey();
  void dispose() {
    myController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
   }

 getText() {
  return myController.text;
 }

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return Scaffold(
    // appBar: AppBar(
    //   title: Text('Retrieve Text Input'),
    // ),
    body: Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
      child: Column(
          children:[
          TextField(
          controller: myController,
         ),
          MaterialButton(
            child: Text('Click Me'),
            onTap:(){
              DeviceApi.getDevices(myController.text)
          }
       ) 
     ])
    ),
  );
 }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the incomplete information I provided for the question. in the end, I found another solution using SharedPreferences. Nevertheless, thanks for the answer 